# math behind complex numbers C||RLC

Tags: ac, math, physics, formula-derivation

I have a mathematical problem with the following formula.
The goal is to transform this equation to have a seperated real and imaginary part.
I have already done this with several other equasions, but for this particualar one I don't know where to start.

I dont expect you to do the complete work of transforming for me, it would already be very nice if you could give me a hind on how you would start.

Thank you in advance!

C||RLC

[image: The formula]

---

This is my current progress:

[image: progress]

My question is:

How can I get rid of the imaginary part jωC2*R?

When the denominator is completely real I can just split up the formula and have an imaginary and a real part.

Comment: \${1 \over j} = -j\$

Comment: Multiply both numerator and denominator by the conjugate of the denominator. If you have \$\frac{a+bi}{c+di}\$, you can then do \$\frac{a+bi}{c+di}\cdot\frac{c-di}{c-di}\$

Comment: Because you must not alter the value of the whole expression you are required to multiply both - numerator and denominator - with the same expression.

Answer (score 1):

At first, I would multiply the numerator N(jw) and the denominator D(jw) with jwC2. As a next step you can rewrite the denominator to get the form **D(jw)=R(D)+jIm(D).** Use also the identity 1/j=-j.

Because it is your goal to have a denominator that is pure real you can multiply N(jw) as well as D(jw) with the conjugate-complex expression **[R(D)-jIm(D)]**. Now - because the denominator is real - you can identify the real as well as imag. part of the numerator N(jw). As a last step, both parts must be devided by the real denominator.